# javascript form validation for date & Time

Tags: javascript

I am writing a javascript to validate **Date&time** based on the **two Dropdowns selected**

Based on the dropdown change the validation has to be changed on **Date&Time** field

I am looking for the validation popup some thing like:

1. **Entered Date&Time should be on or before 1 AM (Midnight) same day**

Comment: Why aren't you using a framework like Dojo toolkit or jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that a framework would help immensely (and I'm sure you'll get lot of suggestions to move to one) but if you're just looking for better Date handling you might want to look at my [DP_DateExtensions](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/) component.

It'll allow you to very simply parse dates (create date objects from your drop-down field values using the Date.parseFormat() method) and then do date math and comparisons on them (in your case using *date*.compare() to compare the entered date to your target date).

You can then use the timeFormat() and dateFormat() methods to display date/times exactly as you want.

The component's old... but well seasoned and, at least to me, insanely useful.